# Running while with empty body runs forever

Tags: java

I build following democode to test the java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.runAsync function:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.runAsync(    () ->{startCall(1);});
        java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.runAsync(    () ->{startCall(2);});
        java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.runAsync(    () ->{startCall(3);});
        //Add sleep if case mainthread is to fast
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        while (!RunningTasks.isEmpty());
        System.out.println("Shutting down");
    }

    private static List<String> RunningTasks=new ArrayList<String>(); 

    private static void startCall(int cn) {

        RunningTasks.add("TASK"+cn);

        int sleeptime = (int) (Math.random()*10*1000);

        System.out.println("Sleeptimer: "+sleeptime+" for instance: "+cn);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Task "+cn+" finished");
        RunningTasks.remove("TASK"+cn);
        System.out.println("RunningTasks: "+RunningTasks.size() +" is empty? "+RunningTasks.isEmpty());
    }       
}
```

If I run this code in my eclipse in normal mode (so just hit run) everything works expect, that the while loop seems to never really stop meaning "Shutting down" never gets printed.

If I run the code in DebugMode and set a breakpoint on the condition as soon as *RunningTasks: 0 is empty? true* gets printed, the while detects that the condition is false and exits.

If I put some peace of code, for example a sysout command into the while loop it also exits like expected.

Did I miss something or is this indeed a Java bug?

Comment: Use of `while (!RunningTasks.isEmpty());` is not really recommended. I suggest you to have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture and especially to chapter 8.

Comment: The `remove` function returns a boolean. Please change your program to print the result of the remove call and post the output in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While running the code the programm might be optimized. So it can happen that your computer caches the result of the condition in the while loop. If you want to prevent this caching you can write:

```
private static volatile List<String> RunningTasks=new ArrayList<String>();
```

The **keyword** `volatile` tells the computer to not cache the results so that you really look up the result of `RunningTasks.isEmpty()` in every iteration without using a cached value.

Comment: No, volatile won't help here (and if it helps it is pure luck) because ArrayList is not a thread-safe data-structure. One either has to use a mutex or a thread-safe data-structure (which could internally use a mutex or use atomics).

Comment: Didn't know that. Interesting question + answer (+1 both). Just want to add that ArrayList is no thread safe and should be synchronized. For example: private static List<String> RunningTasks = synchronizedList( new ArrayList<String>()); prevents infinite loop too.

Comment: @SebastianMarsching I reproduced it and volatile does help defeat the infinite loop. But you are right that thread safety is an additional concern.