# Java while loop condition changed by other object

Tags: java

I have a Java code not working: the problem is a while loop that never ends even though it should.
In a class `Engine`, I have the following code:

```
public class Engine {
    private boolean termine = false;

    // Code

    public boolean tour(int joueur) {
        stade = 1;
        while(!termine);
        termine = false;
        stade = 0;
    }

    // Code

    public void setTermine(boolean t) {
        termine = t;
    }
}
```

The variable `termine` is modified by the method `setTermine`, called by another class `GestionClavier`:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
public class GestionClavier implements KeyListener {
    Engine engine;

    GestionClavier(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // Code
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_T) {
            engine.setTermine(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the variable `termine` is modified by `GestionClavier`, but somehow `Engine` still doesn't exit the `while(!termine)` loop. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: Is the loop running on a different thread than the thread calling setTermine? Try making the boolean variable volatile.`private volatile boolean termine = false;`

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot

Comment: Doesn't that now produce a hot 100% utilized CPU core? maybe a Thread.sleep(42); would be nice within the loop.

Comment: I fixed it with Eran's method, making the `termine` variable volatile—even if I don't really understand what it means.

Comment: @Raph see this related question, quite similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889126/running-while-with-empty-body-runs-forever

Comment: has todo with caching vs. read this.termine field every time.

Answer (score -1):

The Problem is with **';'**

```
 public boolean tour(int joueur) {
        stade = 1;
        while(!termine)  // Remove semicolon   while(!termine); 
        termine = false;  
        stade = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Then why have a `while` loop at all? I think OP means to let the code halt until it is changed by another piece of code.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. I'm quite certain the loop was supposed to have an empty body.

Comment: The semicolon is meant to be there; the `while` loop is empty, it is simply supposed to block the `tour()` method until the key T is pressed

Comment: @Amessihel no, it will never terminate, because it loops as long as termine is false.

Comment: Adding to @Tarun I would also recommend if you could have brackets for the while loop, else it only takes care of the next line, and stade=0 will always get executed.